# pytorch's augmented assignment and requires_grad

Tags: python, pytorch, augmented-assignment

Why does:

```
with torch.no_grad():
     w = w - lr*w.grad
     print(w)
```

results in:

```
tensor(0.9871)
```

and

```
with torch.no_grad():
     w -= lr*w.grad
     print(w)
```

results in:

```
tensor(0.9871, requires_grad=True)
```

Aren't both operations the same?

Here is some test code:

```
def test_stack(): 
    np.random.seed(0)
    n = 50
    feat1 = np.random.randn(n, 1)
    feat2 = np.random.randn(n, 1)
    
    X = torch.tensor(feat1).view(-1, 1)
    Y = torch.tensor(feat2).view(-1, 1)
    
    w = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True)
    
    epochs = 1
    lr = 0.001
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i in range(len(X)):
            y_pred = w*X[i]
            loss = (y_pred - Y[i])**2
            loss.backward()
            
            with torch.no_grad():
                #w = w - lr*w.grad  # DOESN'T WORK!!!!
                #print(w); return
                w -= lr*w.grad
                print(w); return

                w.grad.zero_()
```

Remove the comments and you'll se the requires_grad disappearing. Could this be a bug?

Comment: for me both ways result in `tensor(1.0911)`

Comment: Really?! What is the Torch version you are using? I have 1.13.1+cu117
I'll add some test code to my question above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it boggled me. I asked chatGPT, and it turns out that normal subtraction creates a **new tensor** with `requires_grad` set to `False`, while augmented assignment works **in-place**, retaining the `requires_grad` property.

### Let's see with an example

We will track the `id` of the object via the `id()` function, which returns an integer that's unique for every object in memory.

##### Normal subtraction

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor(5.0, requires_grad = True)
id1 = id(x) # the id for the tensor object referenced by x
y = torch.tensor(3.0)
x = x - y
id2 = id(x) # the id for the new tensor object referenced by x
print(id1 == id2) # prints False
print(x.requires_grad) # prints False
```

- The reason why the ids are different is because the subtraction operation returns a different tensor object, with `requires_grad` set to `False`
- Using the old `x` handle has no effect on whether or not a new object gets created.
- Using the old handle only means that we no longer have a reference to the old tensor object, and it will be garbage collected.

##### Now let's see augmented assignment

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor(5.0, requires_grad = True)
id1 = id(x) # the id for the tensor object referenced by x
y = torch.tensor(3.0)
x -= y
id2 = id(x)
print(id1 == id2) # prints True
print(x.requires_grad) # prints True
```

Now, with augmented assignment, the subtraction is in place. This means the old object is modified, without having to create a new one. Because of that, the ids before and after subtraction remains the same, because x still references the same object.

### But wait, why do subtraction and augmented assignment work differently?

This is because they can be implemented using different dunder methods. I think this [forum](https://discuss.python.org/t/difference-between-and-operator-in-python/12899) can explain well. But, the gist is, python understands these operators differently. They're not just syntactic sugar. This is why there's a discrepancy between the two seemingly identical operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wish I'd know the reason behind that lack of uniformity. I'd expect both would to do exactly the same. A bug maybe?

Comment: @TonyPower Maybe. I don't know how it's implemented under the hood. But you're right, it's confusing, and the behavior is not immediately obvious.